# Reduce volume of 'blip' sound on Macbook

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sound-volume

When I click on the volume buttons I hear the 'blip' sound. I got [how to disable it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/28136/how-can-i-retain-volume-settings-upon-plugging-in-different-speakers-headphones/28145)

But generally it is good to get feedback sound so I don't want to turn it off completely. I want to reduce the volume feedback because it has some kind of high volume. Is there a way to do that without turning off completely?

Comment: If you just occasionally want sound feedback, and have the blip sound disabled, you can hold down the Shift key to have volume feedback. Not sure if that would be of any use to you.

Comment: The question isn't very clear ... the blip sound reflects the volume of your speakers. If it's loud, doesn't that mean your volume is just too high?

Comment: Also, if you don't want to hear the feedback at all, you can hold shift while pressing the volume keys, as bassplayer7 mentioned -- it works both ways.

Comment: @jmk, I don't know why you think it is not very clear. I mean exactly as you have said "the blip sound reflects the volume of your speakers. If it's loud, doesn't that mean your volume is just too high?" yes, it is. It has a loud volume but the other sounds are not that high. As an example; let's say there is some music at the level (for my ears) 50. I want to make it higher. I push the volume increase button. I hear the volume feedback such as the level 70. But music volume is not even 60 after the volume increase. So I mean feedback volume is too high. I want to make it 40 instead of 70 or 0

Comment: I see. Have you checked whether the the volume in your music player (e.g., iTunes) is at full volume? That might help prevent the feedback sound from being so much louder than your music.